# How to add a property in the DOM Object's constructor.prototype in Internet Explorer<=IE8?

Tags: javascript, dom, object, constructor

I want to add some custom properties to the prototype of the DOM Object,I am able to access the `Object.constructor.prototype` and add properties when I am working with Firefox or Chrome but can't access it in IE8 and less because it says there is no constructor of the Object.Is there any work around for it?

Comment: Why are you doing this? And why aren't you just modifying `Object.prototype`?

Comment: because `Object.prototype` isn't available in IE8

Comment: Yes it is, depending on your document mode. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/f5s9ycex(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @RomanticElectron Since when?

Comment: @lan I m really targeting the constructors prototype... and I can't get to define properties on `Object.prototype` via `Object.defineProperties` in any of the browsers..and I was mistaken that I wasn't getting `Object.prototype` ...sorry for that

Comment: @RomanticElectron That's because `Object.defineProperties` isn't supported in all browsers - http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.defineProperties . Again, why are you trying to change `.consructor`'s `prototype`?

Answer (score -1):

The [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/c1hcx253%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) property of an object is supported by IE8 in quirks and standards mode, check and see what mode the document is rendering in.  You can enforce standards mode by ensuring that you have a doctype at the top of your page.  However, `Object.constructor === Function`, so when you are modifying the `Object.constructor.prototype`, youre really modifying `Function.prototype`, which I don't think is what you are looking to do.

Comment: Nops that exactly what I am looking for and the browser mode is IE 8

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900(v=vs.85).aspx.  Is this what you are trying to achieve?